# lxml to grab All items that share a certain xpath

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to grab all prices from a website, using the xpath. all prices have the same xpath, and only [0],  or I assume the 1st item works... let me show you:

```
webpage = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")

dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))

print(dom.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/article/div[1]/div[2]/div')[0].text)
```

This successfully prints the 1st price!!!
I tried changing "[0].text" to 1, to print the 2nd item but it returned "out of range".
Then I was trying to think of some For loop that would print All Items, so I could create an average.

Any help would be Greatly appreciated!!!

## ***I apologize edited in is the code***

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import requests

URL = "https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?d=GPU&N=601357247%20100007709"

#HEADERS = you'll need to add your own headers here, won't let post.

webpage = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")

dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))

print(dom.xpath('/html/body/div[10]/div[4]/section/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/strong')[0].text)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Without knowing what the actual document looks like (or at least the general vicinity of the element you successfully grabbed, it's impossible to say what went wrong. Please include at least the relevant part of the html, and perhaps provide a link to the actual page, if it is public. Also, when you say "to 1", that's to say you changed "[0].text" to "[1].text", correct?

Comment: yes, sorry I edited and pasted in all of the code.

Comment: ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 \
            (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',\
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})

Comment: That's what I used for "HEADERS =" which should work for you

Comment: If you go to that URL, all of the prices have that same xpath. I assume "[0].text" is selecting the 1s items price because that's what it prints. But I can't get it to print the 2nd, 3rd, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You could just use css selectors which, in this instance, are a lot more readable. I would also remove some of the offers info to leave just the actual price.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from pprint import pprint

r = requests.get("https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?d=GPU&N=601357247%20100007709", headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.text, features="lxml")
prices = {}

for i in soup.select('.item-container'):
    if a:=i.select_one('.price-current-num'): a.decompose()
    prices[i.select_one('.item-title').text] = i.select_one('.price-current').get_text(strip=True)[:-1]

pprint(prices)
```

---

prices as list of floats

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from pprint import pprint

r = requests.get("https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?d=GPU&N=601357247%20100007709", headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.text, features="lxml")
prices = []

for i in soup.select('.item-container'):
    if a:=i.select_one('.price-current-num'): a.decompose()
    prices.append(float(re.sub('\$|,', '', i.select_one('.price-current').get_text(strip=True)[:-1])))

pprint(prices)
```

Comment: I've been playing around with this a little. It definitely works better than mine... but mine just printed out the #, I was hoping next step to save those numbers into like a list of variables and get an average, but I can't do that as easily with this method.

Comment: You want the number of offers in a list? And what happens with the items with no listing of offers? Do you put 0 or skip? Do you need to remove the text _offers_ ? Do you still need to associated those numbers with a listing or do you just need the list of numbers?

Comment: You can simply grab the list of offers before looping and decomposing. See edit.

Comment: or sorry I mean like just the #($-wise). Like just the [800] in [$800]

Comment: like not even the name of the item or anything :)

Comment: I really appreciate the help, and the time - I am very thankful for that btw! :) but basically - in my program it will print just "$896"(of the 1st item), but I wish to print every single item on the entire page (eventually even page 2,3,4,5,etc... I am kind of confused on how to do that

Comment: So you want the average cost?

Comment: I've added an edit to give you a list of prices. If you want to do multiple pages please open a new question and show what you have tried and explain where stuck.